# Excel - Square shapes change names when value from list change

Tags: excel

I have submitted question on [Excel - Autoshape get it's name from cell (value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824419/excel-autoshape-get-its-name-from-cell-value/7833086#7833086) but every my reply get's deleted so I will open new one.... please don't delete now

This is file and works fine but I have to use now only square shapes

[File](http://www.miroslav.ca/ShapesV2.xls)

in way home1, home2, office1, office2, stair1, stair2.. to indicate locations that if user change home in the list to building it changes only squares that have that name and not others...? or office to elevator only office shapes are updated

this column A with shapes can be deleted and leave only B name and C number as I use only squares

sorry don't know so much about VBA

check image

[image](http://www.miroslav.ca/img.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a `_Change` event on the shapes worksheet.  Add this to the `Shapes` sheet vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim nw As Variant
    Dim old As Variant

    ' in case there is an error...
    On Error GoTo CleanUp 
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, [Shape])
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ' Save new name
        nw = Target
        ' Prevent events firing while we change sheet values 
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' Get previous name
        Application.Undo
        old = Target
        ' Restore new name
        Target = nw
        ' Rename selected Shapes
        For Each shp In Me.Shapes
            If shp.Name Like old & "#*" Then
                shp.Name = nw & Mid(shp.Name, Len(old) + 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If
CleanUp:
    ' Re-enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this is awesome... What will be modification to use letters on second column instead of digits?

Comment: Just change `shp.Name Like old & "#*"` to shp.Name Like old & "*".  Then any shape name that begins with the old name will be changed

Comment: If this solves your problem, you should accept the answer (click the tick)

Comment: thanks ... VBA looks for changes in first column only if I'm right like home,elevator etc... and what I'm trying now if I change values in second list (1.2.3 to left, right) that shape name update but that doesn't work... :( like from home1 to homeleft , first column is home, second is left

Comment: The code `Set rng = Intersect(Target, [Shape])'  'If Not rng Is Nothing Then ...` checks for change in first column.  Just repeat the code using `[Number]` instead of `[Shape]`

Comment: I'm getting error when add new one but I need that script check for changes in second column also... Thank you thank you for help